# RecipeDataBase_Impl does not exist android studio

Tags: java, database, kotlin, dependency-injection, android-room

I would be very grateful if someone help me with this error,
I tried many solutions but unfortunately didn't work.
This is logcat error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> >java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity >ComponentInfo{com.solution/com.h
> solution.view.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.solution.data.RecipeDataBase. RecipeDataBase_Impl does not exist

I tried to update the whole app but still facing the problem.